# help prove this propositional logic equivalency

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, propositional-calculus, conjunctive-normal-form

I'm really stuck on proving this propositional logic equivalency. I've tried De Morgan's law, and double negation to see if I could get it, but no luck. Any help is greatly appreciated! P.S Please, tell me which laws you use to prove it.

$(p \land q) \lor (q \land r) \lor (r \land p) \equiv (p \lor q) \land (q \lor r) \land (r \lor p)$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: @OP: Have you tried [distributive laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributive_property#Rule_of_replacement)?

Comment: I gave those a shot. They reduce part of it, but I'm not sure what to do after that. Like it brings the first half down to (q ∧ (r ∨ p)) ∨ (r ∧ p).

Comment: No negation, so no DeMorgan application here. As said, use distributivity.

Answer (score 0):

$(p\lor q)\land(p\lor r)\land(q\lor r)$

$\Leftrightarrow (p\lor(q\land r))\land(q\lor r)$ by the distributive law

$\Leftrightarrow ((p\lor(q\land r))\land q)\lor ((p\lor(q\land r))\land r)$ again by the distributive law

$\Leftrightarrow ((p\land q)\lor((q\land r)\land q))\lor ((p\land r)\lor((q\land r)\land r))$ again by the distributive law

$\Leftrightarrow (p\land q)\lor(q\land r\land q)\lor (p\land r)\lor(q\land r\land r)$ dropping parantheses since certain parts are well defined

$\Leftrightarrow (p\land q)\lor(r\land q\land q)\lor (p\land r)\lor(q\land r\land r)$ by commutative law

$\Leftrightarrow (p\land q)\lor(q\land r)\lor (p\land r)\lor(q\land r)$ by idempotent law

$\Leftrightarrow (p\land q)\lor (p\land r)\lor(q\land r)\lor(q\land r)$ by commutative law

$\Leftrightarrow (p\land q)\lor(q\land r)\lor (p\land r)$ by idempotent law

Hence, $(p\lor q)\land(p\lor r)\land(q\lor r) \Leftrightarrow (p\land q)\lor(q\land r)\lor (p\land r)$